# Send html input value in ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am having a problem in getting the html input value in the ruby 
`periodically_call_remote`...

For example:

i have an input named `my_input`. Now i want to have this in the `periodically_call_remote`.

```
<input name="my_input" />

periodically_call_remote(:url=>{:action=>"action_name", :controller=>"controler_name", nvalue=>"value_of_my_input"}, frequency=>"5")
```

This is the call in which i want to have the input value in the value_of_my_input.

**rails gem version: 2.3.5**

how will i achieve this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have achieved what i wanted... the code is as:

```
periodically_call_remote(:url=>{:controller=>"controller_name", :action=>"action_name"), :with=>"'name='+jQuery('#id').val()")
```

Thnx for your help and time brothers...

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are using rails 2.3.5 but "periodically_call_remote" is deprecated in Rails 3, so I recommend that you use something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
  $.get('<%= url_for :action=>"action_name", :controller=>"controler_name", :value=>"value_of_my_input" %>', function(value) {
    $('#my_input').val(value);
});
},5000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You need response by your action `action_name` a javascript script doing the update of you input.

```
$('#id_of_my_input').val('<%= @my_new_value %>')
```